# Add </LI> closing tags to each REGEX match in string

Tags: c#, html, regex, string

I have an HTML document with unclosed `<LI>` elements. I need to append `</LI>` to the end of each `</OBJECT>` that follows the opening `<LI>` tag.
**Note:** Objects that aren't preceded by `<LI>` should not have an `</LI>` tag appended to `</OBJECT>`

```
<OBJECT value="example">
    <param name="Joe">

    </OBJECT>
<UL>
    <LI> <OBJECT type="example">
        <param name="Pat">
        <param name="State" value="Arizona">
        </OBJECT>
    <UL>
        <LI> <OBJECT type="example">
            <param name="Steve">
            <param name="State" value="California">
            </OBJECT>

<OBJECT type="text/sitemap">
    <param name="Carol">

    </OBJECT>
```

This is what I've got so far with no luck

```
private void closeListItems(string doc)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Regex rx = new Regex("(<LI>.(.+?)</OBJECT>)", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    string[] hhcFile = File.ReadAllLines(doc);
    string temp = "";
    foreach (string line in hhcFile)
    {
        temp += line + "\n";
    }
    temp = rx.Replace(temp, "<LI>");
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath + "\\liFix.txt");
    sw.Write(temp);
    sw.Close();

}
```

UPDATE: I also tried this with no luck:

```
private void closeListItems(string doc)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    string[] hhcFile = File.ReadAllLines(doc);
    string temp = "";
    bool liOpen = false;
    foreach (string line in hhcFile)
    {
        temp = line;
        if (line.Contains("<LI>"))
        {
            liOpen = true;
        }
        if (line.Contains("</OBJECT>") && liOpen == true)
        {
            temp.Replace(temp, temp + "</LI>");
            liOpen = false;
        }
        sb.Append("\n" + temp);
    }
    File.WriteAllText("fixLi.txt", sb.ToString());

}
```

Comment: *I have an HTML document with unclosed `<LI>` elements.* — No, you don't. The end tag for li elements is optional in HTML so they are closed (just not explicitly).

Comment: That's valid HTML, the closing `</li>` is optional. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: [obligatory regex + html link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/19068)

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack does not properly parse unclosed LI tags (despite my efforts of recompiling HAP through the source code with modifications to fix it). The <LI> tags differentiate between two types of objects that I need parsed using XPATH.

Comment: @Quentin "...it's sometimes appropriate to parse a limited, known set of HTML."

Comment: It is also useful to properly define a problem.

Comment: @Quentin - When I saw this question in the list, I was going to link to that 'parsing HTML with RegEx' link, but you beat me to it. `:-)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is just in terms of your update:

string.Replace returns a string. Strings are immutable in C# which means you can't directly change the string. Any operation that appears to change the string actually returns one.

Therefore, this line:

```
temp.Replace(temp, temp + "</LI>");
```

..does nothing. It should be:

```
temp = temp.Replace(temp, temp + "</LI>");
```